# sql concatenation in SELECT

Tags: sql

In the SELECT clause I have `SELECT isnull(client,'')+'-'+isnull(supplier,'')`, is it ok to write `GROUP BY client,supplier`, or should I mandatorily write `GROUP BY isnull(client,'')+'-'+isnull(supplier,'')`?

Comment: MySQL? SQL server? Oracle?

Comment: SQL...I wasn't sure if in GROUP BY and ORDER BY it should be the same as in SELECT.

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ANSI/ISO. Your query uses some product specific extensions, looks like MS SQL Server.

Comment: Consider the client 'A' with supplier 'B-C', and the client 'A-B' with supplier 'C'. Do you want separate rows for those?

Comment: the relationship is one to one. A record (transaction) can be either a purchase or a a sale. the concatenated field should bring the third party, which can be either a supplier or a customer.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to `GROUP BY client, supplier`. That way if there's any indexer available it can be used. While the other solution also works it would require a whole table scan in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Just list the column names. You can verify this by executing it, and also look at execution plans to verify index usage.

```
GROUP BY client,supplier
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly say **group by client, supplier**

Please see sample data and result after running query.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHEHu.png)